# Configuration for Microsoft Authentication Using JWT Token in Startup Class

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to configure both `JWT` authentication and `Microsoft` authentication in asp.net core web `API` startup class. But when I use the below code it shows scheme already exist bearer error. How do I resolve?

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

    var jwtTokenConfig = Configuration.GetSection("JwtToken").Get<JwtConfiguration>();
    var scope = "api://4590ab01-d5b1-42af-ab22-5ad0215ad3b4";
    var audience = new List<string>
                    {
                    $"{scope}"
                    };
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = jwtTokenConfig.Issuer,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtTokenConfig.Secret)),
                    ValidAudience = jwtTokenConfig.Audience,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
                };
            })
    .AddJwtBearer("AzureAd", options =>
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidAudiences = audience,
                ValidIssuers = new List<string>
                                {
                                $"https://sts.windows.net/eb971100-6f99-4bdc-8611-1bc8edd7f436",
                                $"https://sts.windows.net/eb971100-6f99-4bdc-8611-1bc8edd7f436/v2.0"
                                }
            })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration);

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
                                JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "AzureAd");
        defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add `AddJwtBearer()` and `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi()` in your `services.AddAuthentication()`. Check `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi()`'s source code, You will find it have a paramater `string jwtBearerScheme = "Bearer"`. If you don't change it, It will conflict with `AddJwtBearer()`, So you just need to give it a new name:

`.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "AzureAd", "{new name}");` and it will work fine.

**"AzureAd" is the default value, you don't need to change it.**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Xinran Shen I tried the above the code but its not working as expected. Again it shows scheme already exist error. Is there any other way to implement both JWT authentication and Microsoft authentication configuration in startup class. and thanks for your information and is there any way kindly share the examples.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code after you changed?

Comment: services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer({
TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameter{ }})                                                          
 .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration,"{microsoft}")   services.AddAuthorization(options =>{
var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme"AzureAd");
defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build()

Comment: Hi @senthup, Check my answer. `.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi()` has three paramters, In your code, you just add `{microsoft}` in it. So `{microsoft}` will just replace the second default parameter`("AzureAd")`, Not the `Bearer`. You need to change like this `.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "AzureAd", "microsoft");`.

Comment: Hi @Xinran Shen actually thankyou for your valuable information and your code working as expected. and I have one more doubt while am passing the Microsoft token in my code [if (!context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)] isAuthenticated as true so its working fine but if i pass JWT token [if (!context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)] isAuthenticated always it returns false. is there any other ways to validate.  And I will attach my code below.

Comment: services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer("jwt",o=>{
     o.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
     o.SaveToken = true;
     o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
      ValidateIssuer = true,
      ValidIssuer = jwtTokenConfig.Issuer,
      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
      IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtTokenConfig.Secret)),
      ValidAudience = jwtTokenConfig.Audience,
      ValidateAudience = true,
      ValidateLifetime = true,
      ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
};
})

Comment: Okay @Xinran Shen.

Comment: Hi @Xinran Shen I created the question kindly check it. and the question url is ::: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72136956/if-context-httpcontext-user-identity-isauthenticated-always-returns-false

Answer (score 1):

Here are the settings and configurations for JWT Auth in asp.net core app.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(RoleStrings.Admin, policy => policy.RequireRole(RoleStrings.Admin));
});

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})

.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(configuration.GetSection("JWT:SecretKey").Value)),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        RequireExpirationTime = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true
    };
});
```

Comment: You are configured just JWT authentication only. but i need to configure both JWT authentication and ( Azuread ) Microsoft authentication in a single startup class in asp.net core Web API. anyway thankyou for your information.